# How to reset filefield after select file ExtJs

Tags: javascript, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I try to reset filefield after select file with the same name, but it not work:

```
onUploadPhonesCSV: function (field, value, opts) {
    var inputEl = field.fileInputEl.dom,
        fileList = inputEl.files;
    var file = fileList[0];
    var vm = this.getViewModel();
    console.log(value);
    if (field.isValid()) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
            var myCsv = oFREvent.target.result;
            vm.set('phones', myCsv);
            field.setRawValue("");
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
},
```

Also tried `field.reset()` it not work.
Help me please.